# What function to replace jQT.goTo

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I am trying to convert a jqtouch app that was developed for me to jquery mobile.

I don't know how I should be converting this code

```
showMainMenu: function() {
        Inventory.loadDealers();
        Inventory.enableMenu(false);
        jQT.goTo('#mainmenu');
    },
```

I tried

```
showMainMenu: function() {
        Inventory.loadDealers();
        Inventory.enableMenu(false);
        $('#mainmenu').slideUp('slow', function() {});

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

A "page" in jQuery Mobile consists of an element (usually a div) with a data-role attribute set to "page", within which ther generally tends to be div elements with roles of "header", "content", and "footer", each containing common markup, forms, and custom jQuery Mobile widgets.

Do you have the data-role set on the div?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#mainmenu", { transition: "slideup"} );
```

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/api/methods.html